# Draw Rectangles Over An Image In Horizontal and Vertical Direction

Tags: android, imageview

I want to draw A Rectangle over a Image In Horizontal And Vertical Direction Just Like a Grid.
I can use grid but when I Pan(Drag) image this won't work. The rectangle should also Pan with the Image or shold move with the Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way should be to have a view that draws the shape you want and your image together in a frame layout.

And then you should move the layout of both view rather than the view alone.